# Eclipse freezes when creating a new project or a new class

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I just installed Eclipse in Ubuntu. When I create a new project or create a new class, Eclipse freezes.

The confusing thing is that when I check the workspace, I find the project or the class that I create which means it can create projects and classes but why does it freeze and, in this case, I should kill Eclipse and restart again?

Also, when I write a code in the class and run it, it freezes.

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Mind if you would post more details? Hardware, exact OS and Java versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the version of GTK+3. All what I did is in `eclipse.ini` I included the following two lines:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

before the line `--launcher.appendVmargs`

Comment: strangely enough my problem was solved by doing exactly the opposite of this: removing these lines from eclipse.ini !! (I had added them before)